# FloatingActionButton is taking up the width of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button

More Android Layout woes for the android newbie. I have been trying to learn android programming, and for the most part it is easy(ish), the hardest part is the layout. I have a Tab layout right now that is the "home" view, and on that view I need a floating action button. For some reason the floating action button is taking up the entire width of the screen. The button itself is the correct size, however the layout cuts off the bottom of the screen. I have followed a few tutorials and no matter what I do it always takes the entire width cutting off the bottom of my screen. Screenshot attached of it running in an emulator from Android Studio.
The layout is here...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth.HomeActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/appbar"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:paddingTop="8dp"-->
        <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <!--</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>-->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primaryLightColor" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am filling the view with Fragments and such, but I don't think that would be the problem. Can anyone see why the FloatingActionButton isn't floating, but instead acting as a full linear layout? Thank you so much for the help.

[image]

Comment: just try I'm not sure about the perfect result but please do let me know if it works or not. in you floatingActionButton just make the **scaleType as centreCrop** and then see if it works or not

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma it didn't work, still shows the button across the whole screen. Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

use coordinate Layout for showing floating action button:

Remove floating action Button from your XML code and your XML code should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.fab.MainActivity">


    <include layout="@layout/your_current_layout" /> // your current xml code layout

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Will that ruin the layout that I have that is forcing the tabs to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: That worked, but now the FAB is covering my Tabs at the bottom of the screen. Also, I only want the fab on the "home" tab, not any of the other tabs. Does that change anything?

Comment: If you want to have FAB in a home tab then put the XML code in your home tab activity, not in parent activity.

Comment: You can simply put the FloatingActionButton in your viewPager's Home fragment / view.

Answer (score 0):

You need tu add the FAB only in the home layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>
```